FirebaseMessaging no longer support client upstream sendMessage in iOS?
How to send Upstream FCM messages from iOS? (from 2017) shows that Firebase used to have an option to send messages from iOS using Messaging.messaging().sendMessage().
I've installed FirebaseMessaging v10.24.0 and it seems that this is no longer available for iOS. Is there a replacement for Messaging.messaging().sendMessage() for iOS?
It seems that this feature is available for Android as documented in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/upstream

That's correct. Sending upstream messages through FCM has been removed - not just from iOS, but from all clients. From the top of the page on Sending upstream messages:

Caution: Sending messages (including upstream messages) with the FCM XMPP and HTTP legacy APIs was deprecated on June 20, 2023, and will be removed in June 2024. If you are using the legacy FCM send APIs, we strongly recommend that you migrate to the HTTP v1 API or consider using the Admin SDK to build send requests.

The common way to send upstream messages nowadays is to not use FCM for it at all, but create your own API end point to handle your needs and let your client-side code call that.
